# Using enctype="multipart/form-data" with form, no data gets posted?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is one of the most bizarre bugs I've encountered. I have an HTML form that I use for uploading a file and also sending some additional hidden inputs, which gets processed in a controller method, like bellow.
Just fyi, whether I use the CI form helper functions or write raw HTML code, the output HTML is as follows:

```
<form action="http://mysite/dev/insert-images" id="imageSelectionForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">    

    <input type="file" name="userimage">
    <input type="hidden" name"something"="" value="somevalue">

    <button type="submit">Add image(s)</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I remove the `enctype` from the form, I see the POST-ed data on the "other side". All of it. Otherwise, meaning if I do use the 'multipart' encryption with the form, the POST array appears empty.

```
public function insertImages() {
        echo "in the method";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
```

What is happening exactly?

Comment: what's the resulting html generated from CI?

Comment: Thanks! Getting the output HTML for you, I noticed that a typo existed in the form. You can see it above. That's what was causing the problem. :)